# "Add to Cart" ignores custom options when adding via reviews page

Tags: addtocart

Any idea how to fix this? Would REALLY APPRECIATE

-

This happens on 1.9.1.1 and 1.9.2.0

1.9.2.0
Enter

https://www.airytea.com/buy-organic-black-tea/organic-traditional-jin-jun-mei-black-tea.html

Click Add to Cart, it will fail since you need to select an option, which is ok.

Now instead visit a review page

https://www.airytea.com/review/product/list/id/26/category/3/

Click add to cart. It will add item instantly without asking to select for option.

Expected Result:
Customer must be asked to fill required forms

Actual Result:
Customer can checkout without selecting MUST HAVE options, resulting in loss of data and lower order amount.

1.9.1

https://www.airyhair.com/clip-in-hair-extensions.html

Reviews:

https://www.airyhair.com/review/product/list/id/399/